# Connection between two different methods of finding the coefficients of $f(x+k)$, given the polynomial $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Say $$f(x) = x^2 - 10x + 24$$

and we want to find the coefficients of :
$$g(x)=f(x+k) = (x+k)^2 - 10(x+k) + 24=\color{blue}{a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0}$$

> Method 1
> Using maclaurin series, easy to see that
>
> $\color{blue}{a_0} = g(0) = f(k) = k^2-10k+24$
> $\color{blue}{a_1} = g'(0) = f'(k) = 2k-10$
> $\color{blue}{a_2} = g''(0)/2 = f''(k)/2 = 1$

---

> Method 2
> Repeatedly divide $f(x)$ by $\color{red}{x-k}$
>
> $f(x) = f_1(x)(\color{red}{x-k})+\color{blue}{a_0}$
> $f_1(x) = f_2(x) (\color{red}{x-k})+\color{blue}{a_1}$
> $f_2(x) = f_3(x) (\color{red}{x-k})+\color{blue}{a_2}$

I feel both methods are related, but I haven't been able to comprehend exactly how. These methods seem to link "division" to "differentiation". I think the  "successive" division in method2 is really throwing me off. I seem to not understand how it actually works... I appreciate if you could help me understand how these two methods are related...

---

My thoughts so far

- I completely understand how Method1 works, its because maclaurin series for a polynomial gives the same polynomial back.
- But Method2 is still a bit magic to me... I see that Method2 is using $\color{red}{x-k}$ instead of $\color{red}{x+k}$. Is it because the remainder of $\dfrac{f(x)}{x-k}$ is $f(k)$, not $f(-k)$ ? But why is this the reason ? I think I don't get how repeatedly dividing $\color{red}{x-k}$ is spitting out the coefficients.
- Since I don't understand Method2, I thought contrasting it with Method1 might provide some insight..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method **2.** expresses $\,f(x)\,$ as a polynomial in $\,(x-k)\,$, which can indeed be determined via repeated long division:

$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1 \cdot (x-k) + a_2 (x-k)^2 = a_0 + (x-k) \cdot \underbrace{\big(a_1 + \overbrace{a_2}^{f_2(x)} \cdot (x-k)\big)}_{{f_1(x)}}
$$

Then $\require{cancel}\,g(x)=f(\color{blue}{x+k}) = a_0 + a_1 \cdot \big(\color{blue}{x+\bcancel{k}}-\bcancel{k}\big) + a_2 \cdot \big(\color{blue}{x+\bcancel{k}}-\bcancel{k}\big)^2 = a_0+a_1x+ a_2x^2\,$.

Comment: Ohh.. method2 is expanding $f(x)$ in terms of $x-k$ so that $f(x+k)$ simplifies to the standard form... I get how you're expanding $f(x)$ using repeated division... Clever! Seriously, what should I do to see math as you see ? XD

Comment: @rsadhvika Yes, that's the gist of it. Now that you've seen it once, you'll recognize it next time it comes up, and that's how experience builds.

Comment: Agree! You must have worked v hard to be as good as you're now. I feel repeated division here is like changing base from $x$ to $x-k$, the same method we use when converting between number systems. I dont see much difference between numbers and polynomials after [this exercise](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/upqzldyz5v) ! Thanks again for being so awesome :)